# OAuth access token assistance

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to generate an access token to set OAuth flow but I get a 401 error response "access_denied", suggesting to "Reach out to the LinkedIn Relationship Manager or Business Development team to get the necessary access.

The purpose of my request to set up OAuth is related to a personal proof of concept. I am interested in experimenting and comparing the capabilities of LinkedIn's API with that of Twitter's. Specifically, I wish to explore how much information I can extract from a user profile using these APIs. This includes data like name, academic background, work experience, language proficiency, recent activity, among others. Essentially, I am seeking a functionality akin to LinkedIn's "Save as PDF" feature, but with the ability to provide deeper insights into the account, such as user activity, interactions, shared content, etc.

Additionally, I am interested in understanding whether such a use case could potentially be employed by a company in the future. As this experiment progresses, I am keen to learn about the ethical, legal, and technical considerations that would need to be taken into account if a company were to leverage this type of data extraction in a compliant manner.

I have already contacted LinkedIn support:
To enhance support for our developer community and streamline the process of addressing LinkedIn API-related questions, we have migrated our online support forum from the Developers site to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin.
Tag your question with the #linkedin hashtag: This will help ensure that LinkedIn engineers and experts are alerted to your question and can provide the most relevant assistance

Comment: This is very clearly *not* a stackoverflow question. I think you'll need to find another linkedin contact. Sorry to send you back and forward and disappointing to see linkedin exploit free labour to reduce their support staff.

Answer (score 0):

First, could you update your question, providing a code snippet, and specify at what point of the OAuth2 Authentication flow you find that error?
A screenshot/copy-paste of the response you received helps a lot.

About your question: ensure you're using the correct public and secret keys when authenticating your request.

**Also, did you sign up as a developer on the [LinkedIn Developer Portal](https://developer.linkedin.com/) and *requested access to the SignIn With LinkedIn functionality*?**

Once you've signed up (if you haven't already), under the products tab you can add them right away. You'll need to apply and wait a day or two before they give you access.

Here's how the Products tab looks like for reference:

[image: Products Tab Screenshot]

Ultimately, if you want to gain access to the entirety of users data, I suggest you go down the scraping route - faster, more data, and without API hassle.

In order to get any sort of education data of any user at all you'd need to become a LinkedIn Partner, which is quite hard and requires an already-setup business (already with customers and already using LinkedIn's common APIs).

[In the documentation regarding the OAuth2 authentication flow everything I talked about above is described in detail.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?tabs=HTTPS1#prerequisites) Read through the docs for any other question.

If you found the problem, accept it as a solution and move on, since as Evert specified in his comment, this kind of question isn't really for StackOverflow. LinkedIn doesn't have any support staff for non-members so I decided to answer anyways.
Still, your problem is quite probably caused by not following the docs closely IMHO.